# Javascript Pulldowns which change depending on the previous pulldown?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a series of pulldowns in my form.

Currently each one has the same options available e.g.

> Nurse, Doctor, Cleaning Staff, Porter.

However I was wondering if its possible if in my first pull down when an item gets selected it can be removed from the following pulldowns. Which would reduce errors or duplication of selected options.

Is this possible if so could you link me to some resources or example code as I had no luck googling as I am very much new to javascript etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have several dropdowns, each with the same options, but you want a user to be able to select multiple options (just not the same one twice)?

That sounds like a job for multi-select or checkboxes.

Comment: my options come from a database and are dynamic so I thought a pulldown would be the best way?